# How to call a subclass' method more than once if I don't know how many times I'll have to do that?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, polymorphism

If I have a class that describes for eg. people, named Person and then it has 6 subclasses, such as Child, Adult Man, Adult Woman, etc. They all have an ID, hair color, eye color, etc. it's just their appearance that's different, so all my subclasses contain their own paint() method. Every person has two coordinates to tell where the program has to draw them on the frame, all the subclasses get those coordinates like this:

```
class AdultMan extends Person
{
    AdultMan(int x, int y) {
        super(x,y); 
            // I haven't yet worked with the hair color, eye color...
            // only the coordinates to test my idea out
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            int x = getX();
            int y = getY();
            // The drawing of an adult man from basic shapes 
            // based on the given coordinates (and colors later)
    }
}
```

So in an other class I handle the given data, I put them all in a map like `Map<Integer,Person>` 
(Integer is the ID)
and then in a class that extends Jframe I put the map's values in a collection and iterate over them like this:

```
for (Person person : persons) 
{
  // (persons is the name of my collection)
  if(person.typeName.equals("adultMan"))
  {
     person = new AdultMan(person.x,person.y);
     person.paint(g);
  }
}
```

I have 6 types of people so I want to do this with every type. **The problem is, if there are maximum of 40 people in my map, there can be like 30 adultMan and this will only draw the first one on the frame and skip to the next different type.**

Comment: Wait... You just do not need to check the type before you `.paint()`. This rather looks like a problem in `.paint()` than anything else. Even if you iterate over `Person` objects, calling `.paint()` will call the _actual instance's `.paint()` method_, ie the correct implmenetation for a man, a woman etc.

Comment: If a person is an instance of AdultMan than you don't need to create new AdultMan object you should just invoke paint method on person you got from collection. This will invoke the correct paint method from AdultMan (you should have an abstract paint method defined in class Person to do so). I am not sure why you say the paint will be only performed for first one. You iterate all the objects and all of them will be painted.

Comment: And using a field `typeName` to store the name of the class is no good too - especially when you can just use `instanceof`... --- Though in this case you don't need any `instanceof` - just call it as per above comments.

Comment: I have this: `public void paint(Graphics g){};` in my Person class, but I don't really understand how and where to decide which subclass' paint() method to call.

Comment: Other than the obvious confusion surrounding OOPLs, why wouldn't it keep iterating over the list? It won't stop at the first "adultMan". @user1927323 You don't *need* to decide which class's method to call, that's one of the points of doing OOP in Java.

Comment: @user1927323, you can `persons.add(new AdultMan(...))` because `AdultMan extends Person`. Then you may just invoke `person.paint(g)` and Java will automatically chose the right paint() method for you.

Comment: Your concrete problem is caused elsewhere than shown so far in the question. Based on the code shown so far, there's no problem unless of the completely unnecessary copy construction of the person. Just doing `for (Person person : persons) { person.paint(g); }` is sufficient to perform the desired job. If that fails for some reason, it's more likely that the `paint()` implementation is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your problem, but you seem to have misunderstood how inheritance works in Java.

If you have a class `Person` and a class `AdultMan` inheriting it this implies that you should be able to use an **instance** of an `AdultMan` anywhere a `Person` can be used. This is the essence of [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). So if a method has the following signature:

```
public void tickle(Person p)
```

Then you can call that method with an AdultMan (or any other object who's class inherit Person). Also in Java if a subclass defines the same method signature as a superclass it is said to override that method. This is illustrated by the code below:

```
class Person {
   public void laugh() {
       System.out.pring("Tihi");
   }
}  

class AdultMan extends Person {
   public void laugh() {
       System.out.pring("Hahaha");
   }
}

class AdultWoman extends Person {
   public void laugh() {
       System.out.pring("Hihihi");
   }
}

class Child extends Person { }
```

`AdultMan` and `AdultWoman` overrides the `laugh` method so whenever the `laugh` method is called on an **instance** of those classes that class's method will be called. It doesn't matter if the type of the variable holding the object is a `Person`. if there is a method overriding the laugh method that is the method that get the call. In the case of the `Child` class it does not define it's own `laugh` method and as such simply inherits the method from Person. A runnable example illustrating this would be:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        Person man = new AdultMan();
        Person woman = new AdultWoman();
        Person child = new Child();
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList();
        persons.add(person);
        persons.add(man);
        persons.add(woman);
        persons.add(child);

        for(Person p : persons) {
            System.out.print("Laugh: ");
            p.laugh();
        }
        // This will print:
        // Laugh: Tihi
        // Laugh: Hahaha
        // Laugh: Hihihi
        // Laugh: Tihi
    }
}
```